# Controlling multiple amazon EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance

Which class/method to use to start/stop a List of amazon EC2 instances with java API? I only know the `List<Instance>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startInstances takes a StartInstancesRequest, which has a method .setInstanceIds that allows you to attach a list of instance IDs.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#startInstances%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.StartInstancesRequest%29